# bazel for jni: jni.h file not found

Tags: java-native-interface, bazel

I'm trying to use bazel to build my JNI library (written in C).  No luck after about 4 hours: "jni.h file not found".  How can I put the JDK include directories on the search path?  Tried using absolute paths but bazel rejects those.  Trying to use a new_local_repository for the JDK but cannot see how to make it work.

This is bazel 0.5.3 on MacOS 10.12.6, Java 1.8

Comment: please take a look at [java_toolchain](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/java.html#java_toolchain)

Comment: @Bhavik: how does that help me build a C library that calls into JNI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you depend on `@local_jdk//:jni_header` or some other magic labels from https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/117da7a947b4f497dffd6859b9769d7c8765443d/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/rules/java/jdk.WORKSPACE? However if you're using custom `--java_base` it won't work.

E.g. this works for me:

```
cc_library(
    name = "foo",
    srcs = [ 
        "@local_jdk//:jni_header",
        "@local_jdk//:jni_md_header-linux",
        "foo.cc"
    ],
    includes = [ "external/local_jdk/include/linux" ],
)
```

Comment: what's the magic syntax?  If I try ```cc_library(
    name = "myjni",
    deps = ["@local_jdk//:jni_header", ... etc...``` then I get error `in deps attribute of cc_library rule //:jni: filegroup rule '@local_jdk//:jni_header' is misplaced here (expected cc_inc_library, cc_library, objc_library or cc_proto_library).`

Comment: there's also https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/main/tools/jdk.BUILD but no indication anywhere I can find showing how to use the stuff.

Comment: Edited the answer to have the proper formatting. Please do share with us if you make this work all the way through (maybe post to [bazel-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/bazel-discuss)? Sounds very interesting :).

Comment: thanks, was able to get it compiled based on this (dunno yet if it will actually run, heh).  Two points: put the external labels in `srcs`, not `deps` (and include one for the lib you are wrapping), and external headers must be listed in `includes` - this goes for the lib you are wrapping too. once I have a better understanding of what's going on I'll write a blog post.

Comment: ok, I threw together a blog post.  Not entirely sure it's accurate, feedback welcome.  http://blog.mobileink.com/2017/09/bazel-building-jni-lib.html