# Bazel: Java app with JNI dependency

Tags: java, java-native-interface, bazel

I've managed to build my JNI library (the jar, the jni shared cc_library, the wrapped cc_library) but I don't see how to build a Java app that uses it.  My BUILD is simple:

```
java_binary(
    name = "OCFTestServer",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/java/**/*.java"]),
    deps = ["//:OpenOCF-JNI"])
```

Here `OpenOCF-JNI` looks like this:

```
java_library(
    name = "OpenOCF-JNI",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/**/*.java"]),
    deps = ["libopenocf"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"])
```

And `libopenocf` is:

```
cc_library(
    name = "libopenocf",
    srcs = glob(["src/c/*.c"]) + glob(["src/c/*.h"])
    + ["@local_jdk//:jni_header",
       "@local_jdk//:jni_md_header-darwin"],
    ... etc ...
```

These all build successfully.  However, building does not cause dependencies to be built, which is what I would expect (i.e. building OCFTestServer should cause OpenOCF-JNI to be built, which should cause libopenocf-jni to be built). Shouldn't that happen?

If I build them all using separate steps and then try to run the application (using the OCFTestServer wrapper in bazel-bin), I get `UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libopenocf-jni in java.library.path`.  But from reading the docs I get the impression that this should all be set up automatically (i.e. the needed jni lib should be put in the java.library.path).

What am I doing wrong?  Does anybody have an example of building and using a JNI lib?

Comment: I think your cc_library is supposed to separate its srcs from its hdrs.  Not sure if this is related.

Comment: @kd8azz: afaik `hdrs` is for public (i.e. api) headers. otherwise all headers are considered source files.

Comment: I think this is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46160790/bazel-for-jni-jni-h-file-not-found

Comment: @mhlopko: that item adresses building the libs, but not how to use them in an app.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't notice it's you :)

Answer (score 5):

I created a simple repo: https://github.com/mhlopko/bazel-jni-example to help you get started.

`BUILD`:

```
cc_library(
    name = "main-jni-lib",
    srcs = [
        "@local_jdk//:jni_header",
        "@local_jdk//:jni_md_header-linux",
        "Main.cc"
        ],
    hdrs = [ "Main.h" ],
    includes = [ "external/local_jdk/include", "external/local_jdk/include/linux" ],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "libmain-jni.so",
    deps = [ ":main-jni-lib" ],
    linkshared = 1,
)

java_binary(
    name = "Main",
    srcs = [ "Main.java" ],
    main_class = "Main",
    data = [ ":libmain-jni.so" ],
    jvm_flags = [ "-Djava.library.path=." ],
)
```

`Main.java`:

```
public class Main {
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("main-jni");
  }

  private native int foo();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new Main().foo());
  }
}
```

`Main.h`:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class Main */

#ifndef _Included_Main
#define _Included_Main
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     Main
 * Method:    foo
 * Signature: ()I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Main_foo(JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

`Main.cc`:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Main.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Main_foo(JNIEnv *, jobject) {
   return 42;
}
```

Now by running `bazel run :Main` you should see `42` printed out, that is coming from `Main.cc`. The example clearly needs more polish so it works on other-than-linux platforms, and so it works with the launcher script. You might end up needing multiple `System.loadLibrary` calls, like bazel does in [its windows loader](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/f20ae6b20816df6a393c6e8352befba9b158fdf4/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/windows/jni/WindowsJniLoader.java).

Comment: thanks. q: why is `:libmain-jni.so` in `data` rather than `deps`?

Comment: or 'runtime_deps` for that matter.

Comment: Using data or deps is just a matter of style here. The effect is the same since the data is actually a cc binary, which is allowed as a dependency on java_library.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across your question, while trying to figure out how to link to [malmo](https://github.com/Microsoft/malmo), which I just got working.  It's linking against a static library, so it may or may not help you.

third_party/BUILD:

```
java_import(
    name = "malmo",
    jars = ["MalmoJavaJar.jar"],
    deps = [":libMalmo"],
)

cc_library(
    name = "libMalmo",
    srcs = ["libMalmoJava.so"],
)
```

And then in my actual target:

```
    "//third_party:malmo",
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need to add bazel local_jdk jni and jni_md headers to your package cc_library target. But, you can copy them to your project package.

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/c97c77333cab2b78dc8ac76834fb873389f520d7/src/main/native/BUILD#L4

I have already submit PR to https://github.com/mhlopko/bazel-jni-example project to fix the jni relative path problem. maybe this could help you.