# How to pass path to libjvm.so to bazel build?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, linker, bazel

I'm trying to build TensorFlow which uses Bazel as a default build tool. My code I've added into the project depends on Java and requires `libjvm.so` to be linked.

The problem is that the linker ignores `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and can't find `libjvm.so` at all. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is an example repo that hooks Java with C++ using JNI, you might find it useful: https://github.com/mhlopko/bazel-jni-example

Original SO question: [Bazel: Java app with JNI dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46256118/bazel-java-app-with-jni-dependency?rq=1)