# Bazel: How to build a C++ app that uses the JNI?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, bazel

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46256118/bazel-java-app-with-jni-dependency), @hlopko shows how to build a Java app that calls native code. But how do I build a native app that calls Java code?

My attempt, detailed below, fails with:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to load native library:
```

He is the code. `BUILD.bazel`:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = [
        "main.cc",
        "@local_jdk//:jni_header",
        "@local_jdk//:jni_md_header-linux",
        "@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:current_java_runtime",
    ],
    includes = [ "external/local_jdk/include", 
    "external/local_jdk/include/linux"],
)
```

`main.cc`:

```
#include <jni.h>

int main() {
  JNIEnv *env;
  JavaVM *jvm;
  JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
  JavaVMOption options[0];
  jint res;

  vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_4;
  vm_args.options = options;
  vm_args.nOptions = 0;
  vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;

  /* Create the Java VM */
  res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm,(void**)&env,&vm_args);
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error message continues after the colon, what is the entire error message?

Comment: It does not. Though that's mostly an artifact of `@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:current_java_runtime` causing many libraries that would be dynamically loaded to already be runtime dependencies of the binary. If you link against `libjvm.so` only (which is sufficient), then what comes after the colon is the first library that fails to load (usually, `<absolutepath>/libjava.so` where `<absolutepath>` points somewhere in the `_solibs` directory of library symlinks).

Answer (score 0):

[rules_jvm](https://github.com/fmeum/rules_jni/blob/main/docs/targets.md#libjvm-libjvm_lite) (of which I am the author) offers a target at `@fmeum_rules_jni//jni:libjvm` that you can link against and that behaves just like `libjvm.so`, but automatically finds the library when executed. If you additionally call `rules_jni_init`, it will find the current Java runtime used by Bazel.